# Sound on my headphones is too high

Tags: windows-8, audio, usb-headset

Sound from my USB headphones is way too loud. I have to keep everything on total minimum, otherwise it's too high. Screenshot bellow shows highest acceptable volume for me.

On Youtube where you can set volume it's fine but some programs don't allow to change master volume and it's impossible to reduce volume to acceptable levels.

Is there any software that can reduce volume?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've tried that but it didn't help, actually it made it kind worse. Now low setting in Youtube has no sound at all, no matter what I set in Windows. But when I increase the volume to about 25% it is extremely loud.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've removed the link, please undo whatever you did from that article, I can't think of any reason that should happen, sorry

Comment: Take a look at your audio driver, maybe re-install it.

Comment: I don't have any drivers for it, and when I let windows search for it it says it's already up to date.